# syntax error in c#.net

Tags: c#, database

i write this code to extract the data from textbox to Database but when it goes to the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` code, it shows `Incorrect syntax near '-'.` error .

This is the code i write :

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    string str = "server=localhost;Database=ord-95;Integrated Security=True";
    con.ConnectionString = str;

    //SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con; 



    //DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    cmd.CommandText = " insert into build-seller" +  
        "(name-build, name-Seller, family-Seller)" +
        "values(@name-build, @name-Seller, @family-Seller)"; 

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name-build",txtbuild.Text); 

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name-Seller",txtname.Text);  

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@family-Seller",txtfamily.Text);   

    con.Open();

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();   



    txtamount.Text = "";
    txtbuild.Text = "";
    txtfamily.Text = "";
    txtname.Text = "";
    txtobject.Text = "";
    txtshop.Text = "";
    MessageBox.Show("success !", "msg",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Comment: Add `[]` brackets around each word with `-` and try again. For example: `[build-seller]`, `[name-build]`, etc.

Comment: You cant look at the SQL and unravel the mysterious error message?

Comment: Do not concatenate string that way! [String is immutable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx)!

Comment: Has your problem been solved?

Answer (score 4):

What DBMS are you using? You need to delimit your column names that contain `-` in them with whatever is used by your particular DMBS flavor...

SQL Server uses `[` and `]`, so a select statement would be:

```
SELECT [column-a], [column-b] from [Table-1];
```

Oracle uses `"`, so a select statement would be:

```
SELECT "column-a", "column-b" from "Table-1";
```

MySQL uses back-ticks `, so a select statement would be:

```
SELECT `column-a`, `column-b` from `Table-1`;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is already given but you can also fix:

```
cmd.CommandText = @" insert into build-seller
        (name-build, name-Seller, family-Seller)
        values(@name-build, @name-Seller, @family-Seller)";
```

Comment: I believe that would still error when the DBMS attempts to execute it. The problem isn't so much with the application code, as it is a problem with how the DBMS interprets the `-` in the statement.

Comment: @gmiley I was talking about unnecessary string concatenation.